# NHibernate: Is making session singleton a bad practice?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

In my application I have the session as a singleton object in a `SessionManager` class. Whenever, I need to use it a some part of the application, I do:

```
 using (var session = SessionManager.OpenSession())
 {

 }
```

Is this possibly a bad practice ? If so, any ideas about how I can improve ?

**EDIT**: Here is the implementation of session manager

```
 public static class SessionManager
    {
        private static readonly ISessionFactory sessionFactory;


        static SessionManager()
        {
            sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure().....
        }


        public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
        {
            get { return sessionFactory; }
        }


        public static ISession OpenSession()
        {
            return sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like it's not singleton, but static class

Comment: @Uriil the static class has a static constructor which essentially makes it a singleton by configuring and initializing the session variable inside it only once

Comment: Are you sure your session manager is a session and not the session factory?

Comment: @WiktorZychla edited the question for session manager implementation

Comment: The implementation is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it should be singleton so that it can be shared among different threads withing the application. As these objects are heavy weight because they contains the connection information, hibernate configuration information and mapping files,location path. So creating number of instances will make our application heavy weight. But the session objects are not thread safe.

Only applications that require multiple factories with different configurations have an obvious reason to create and close multiple SessionManager instances.

Single threading it will improve the performance of your application.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the ISession is *not* thread-safe! Therefore, you should have just one ISessionFactory, but one ISession per thread.

Comment: This seems to contradict the accepted answer that states that it should be singleton to share amongst threads?

Comment: Indeed, this answer, IMO, is wrong, as per the NHibernate documentation. Sessions are indeed lightweight, but not session factories.

Comment: I agree.  +1.  What about a Session Factory? Do you put these inside a singleton?

Comment: Well, if you care for my opinion, I don't like singletons, but I do register my session factory on an inversion of control container using singleton lifecycle  - there can be only one! :-)